# Is the tensor product of linear maps defined to be linear or provably linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $S:V\rightarrow X$ and $T:W\rightarrow Y$ are two linear maps between vector spaces. One then defines $S \otimes T:V\otimes W \rightarrow X \otimes Y$ by $(S\otimes T)(v\otimes w) = S(v) \otimes T(w)$ for $v \in V, w \in W$.  But is the further fact that $S\otimes T$ is linear something that needs to be asserted about $S\otimes T$, so that the definition extends to all of $V\otimes W$, or is this fact something that can somehow be proven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

You can obtain $S\otimes T$ by invoking the universal property of the tensor product $V\otimes W$: we have a bilinear map $V\times W\to X\otimes Y$ given by $(v,w)\mapsto S(v)\otimes T(w)$. That this is bilinear follows because it is the composition of the linear map $V\times W\to X\times Y$ given by $S\times T$, followed by the bilinear universal map $u\colon X\times Y\to X\otimes Y$ given by $u(x,y)=x\otimes y$.

By the universal property of the tensor product, this bilinear map induces a (unique) *linear* map $V\otimes W\to X\otimes Y$ given by $v\otimes w\mapsto S(v)\otimes T(w)$, giving that the map you have is necessarily linear.

However, this is technically not a *definition* of $S\otimes T$, but rather a derivation of that map; if you simply try to *define* $S\otimes T$ by the given formula and then attempt to extend it linearly, then you need to show that it is well defined (note that the vectors $v\otimes w$ span $V\otimes W$, but are not a basis, since there are linear relations between them). Once you know it is well defined, you will probably get linearity out of it. But in general proving a map is well-defined on $V\otimes W$ devolves into invoking the universal property above, so you are better off using that directly.

Comment: Thank-you Arturo. To paraphrase what you have said, one must add to the definition that the tensor product that it extends linearly in order for it to be defined on all of  $V \otimes W$, at which point one must show that it is well defined. Is that correct?

Comment: @JonathanLenchner: If you want to go that way, yes; you *could* find a basis for $V\otimes W$ (if $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ are a basis for $V$ and $\{f_j\}_{j\in J}$ are a basis for $W$, then the tensors $e_i\otimes f_j$ with $(i,j)\in I\times J$ are a basis for $V\otimes W$), define it on *them* and then just “extend linearly”, but then you probablly want to verify that it gives the definition you have on pure tensors. In all, you are almost certainly better off invoking the universal property.